# Failed to run query: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am a newbie to php and been trying to get rid of this error for a while now. I believe i have the correct amount of parameters but cant figure out where the problem is. This is my php code below.. any answer is much appreciated. thanks

```
require ("common.php");
$mySessionName = $_SESSION['user']['UserName'];
if(!empty($_POST)){
$sql = "INSERT INTO compliance_requirement(ComplianceName, ComplianceGoal,    ComplianceDescription, ComplianceStartDate, ComplianceEndDate, UserName)''VALUES (:compName, :compGoal, :compDes, :compStart, :compEnd, :$mySessionName)";

$query_paramsm = array(':ComplianceName' => $_POST['compName'], ':ComplianceGoal'=>$_POST['compGoal'], 'ComplianceDescription' => $_POST['compDes'], 'ComplianceStartDate'=>$_POST['compStart'], 'ComplianceEndDate'=>$_POST['compEnd'], 'UserName'=>$_POST['UserName']);

try{ 
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($query_paramsm); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex)
{ 

die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 
header("Location: compliance.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You may want to add which line of code resulted in the error.

Comment: it will be lines 4 and 6 from the code above

Answer (score 0):

Lots of issues. 
1. You have '' in the middle of your query
2.

```
$sql = "VALUES (:compName, ...";
$query_paramsm = array(':ComplianceName' => $_POST['compName'] ...);
```

compName and ComplianceName are two very different strings.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you have in the query `:compName, :compGoal, :compDes, :compStart, :compEnd, :$mySessionName`

have not the same name as in your param array :

```
array(':ComplianceName' => $_POST['compName'], ':ComplianceGoal'=>$_POST['compGoal'], 'ComplianceDescription' => $_POST['compDes'], 'ComplianceStartDate'=>$_POST['compStart'], 'ComplianceEndDate'=>$_POST['compEnd'], 'UserName'=>$_POST['UserName'])
```

look :

```
:compName <> :ComplianceName
:compGoal <> :ComplianceGoal
...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply guys.. so are you suggesting I should replace the values in my array with the ones in my sql query?? i tried doing just that but still error..